# what is the best practice to use in filling a form using selenium webdriver maven project?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a form to be filled with about 10 or more fields and I want to read the data from excel sheet, so what is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best practice is to work step by step, module by module.

If the form has text elements - first click on them, later send keyboards strokes to them. Later change selector and at the end click buttons like submit:

```
 @Test
public void clickElementByID(@Optional String elementID) {
    // click element here
}
  @Test
public void changeTextOnLastClicked( @Optional String textToType) {

// keyboard action here
}

@Test
void clickButtonByID(@Optional String buttonID) {
// click button by I
}
```

Using this practice - if the form structure will change in the future - it will be easy to rearrange the test.